# How to rotate an UIImageView with CATransform3DRotate make an effect like vertical window Opening?

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, transform

hi i want to make an effect like vertical window Opening with rotate an UIImageView with `CATransform3DRotate`.

i was tried this code, but it's horizontal window opening.

```
CALayer *layer = img11.layer;
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 45.0f/180.0 * 3.14, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

Comment: Please always share your attempt before asking for the code to solve a particular problem